# Finding Aggregates of Aggregates with Filters in SQL

Tags: sql, nested, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a raw transactional table that looks something like this:

| Transaction_ID | Transaction_Date | Product_Name | Product_Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9/1/22 | Bowling Ball | 2 |
| 2 | 9/1/22 | Bowling Ball | 1 |
| 3 | 9/1/22 | Bowling Pin | 10 |
| 4 | 9/2/22 | Bowling Ball | -5 |

To summarize the daily sales of each product, I can use the following code:

```
SELECT
Transaction_Date,
Product_Name,
SUM(Product_Qty) as Daily_Sold
FROM MyTable
Group By 1, 2
```

My goal is to find the date that each product launched. I would have just grabbed the minimum date for each product in the transactional table; however, due to the structure of my data, some products show negative TOTAL transactions (likely test transactions in our point of sale system--these consist of both positive quantities and negative quantities but they total negative over the course of the day) *before* they launch. So, my real goal is to find the minimum date where each product had a TOTAL units sold greater than 0. Is there a simple way to do this in one query? The only solution I have found so far is as follows:

```
SELECT
Product_Name,
MIN(Transaction_Date) as Launch_Date

FROM

(SELECT
Transaction_Date,
Product_Name,
SUM(Product_Qty) as Daily_Sold
FROM MyTable
Group By 1, 2
HAVING Daily_Sold > 0)

Group By 1
```

I am hoping to avoid this nested query, because my real queries aren't quite this simple (they involve joins and a lot of filters). I am using Snowflake if that is helpful. Anyone able to find a simpler way to solve what I am looking for? Maybe a window function or something?

Answer (score 1):

Using QUALIFY clause to find first transaction date per product:

```
SELECT Transaction_Date,
       Product_Name,
       SUM(Product_Qty) as Daily_Sold
FROM MyTable
Group BY Transaction_Date,Product_Name
HAVING Daily_Sold > 0
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Product_Name ORDER BY Transaction_Date) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested but:

```
SELECT Transaction_Date, Product_Name
     , SUM(Product_Qty) OVER (PARTITION BY Transaction_Date, PRODUCT_NAME) 
     , FIRST_VALUE(TRANSACTION_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT_NAME ORDER BY TRANSACTION_DATE) 
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: that's an interesting approach to use partitions for each column! Unfortunately, the first value column still contains the first date where any transaction appears, even if it was on a testing day where the day ended up with a negative total.

Comment: And what if you do
FIRST_VALUE(CASE WHEN Product_Qty >= 0 THEN TRANSACTION_DATE END) 
and filter out the results where first value is null ?

Comment: I assume you dont want to sum those either, so I would filter with a WHERE clause. Your HAVING clause filter on the aggregate which makes me a little confused. Perhaps you should add some sample data and expected result. Eventhough snowflake does not exist there, I would recomend https://dbfiddle.uk/